# Textbutton not working and scaling issues

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I've created a table with scened2d that contains buttons, but i have many issues with thoses buttons.

First issue is scaling, whenever i try to set a button's with and height an issue appear
when i set it with :

```
table.add(btn).with(100).height(30);
```

or

```
btnStyle.up.setMinWidth(80);
btnStyle.up.setMinHeight(40);
btnStyle.down.setMinWidth(80);
btnStyle.down.setMinHeight(40);
```

the button is correctly scaled but the background is acting weird

[image: Buttons][1]

But if i don't set their with and height, their background are normal but the buttons are way too big

Second issue, the buttons don't "work" as i can't click on then (nothing change)
here is the code

```
// style
final Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/glassy-ui.json"));
final BitmapFont font = skin.getFont("font");
final TextButton.TextButtonStyle btnStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
btnStyle.font = font;
btnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
btnStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button-down");
btnStyle.up.setMinWidth(80);
btnStyle.up.setMinHeight(40);
btnStyle.down.setMinWidth(80);
btnStyle.down.setMinHeight(40);

// buttons
Textbutton btn = new TextButton("some text", btnStyle);
```

how can i scale my buttons correctly and what could cause the buttons to stop working ?

(there is already a question about buttons scaling but it didn't helped much)

Comment: Don't set minWidth and height. Set prefWidth and height. The ones you're using are a hint that the drawables cannot be possibly drawn smaller than the size you give which might be messing it up. It's not well documented.

Comment: setHeight on a button make it look like the screenshot i provided, and i can't find setPrefWidth anywhere

Comment: Increase the viewport of your ``stage.camera``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the clicks on the button, you have to add a ChangeListener.

The assets you are using as button background are too big, or their padding is too big. Use the [Skin Composer](https://ray3k.wordpress.com/software/skin-composer-for-libgdx/) to get a preview for your skin.

Answer (score 0):

With the buttons not working, did you remember to call setInputProcessor on your stage?